# Two virtually identical javascripts; one works, the other doesn't

Tags: javascript, razor

I have two sets of JavaScript/Razor-based functionality which are nearly identical, but one works as expected and the other doesn't.

In fact, the second (non-functioning) set of controller action, partial view, and script was copy-pasted directly from the first (functioning) set. The only change I made was removing an unnecessary ID being passed (OP should specify where), ran the code, and it didn't work.

Can anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

#### Use Case + Expected Behavior:

Both sets are intended to call a controller method that does the following:

1. Get a Partial Result view
2. Display that Partial Result view within in a specified (and empty) div.

#### Current Behavior:

The first (functional) set correctly gets the view and displays it in the specified div.  The second (non-functional) set gets the view, but then loads a new, blank page with just that view in it.

---

The following are all from the non-functional set

#### JS Script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.rollInit').on('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $.get('@Url.Action("RollInits")', function (result) {
                        $('#initiativerolls').prepend(result);
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
```

#### Controller Action:

```
        public ActionResult RollInits()
        {
            RNGCSP rng = new RNGCSP();
            var inits = new List<VMInitiatives>();
            foreach (var init in db.Initiatives)
            {
                var newInit = new VMInitiatives()
                {
                    Result = init.CharacterName + ": " + (rng.RollDice(20) + init.InitiativeBonus).ToString()
                };
                inits.Add(newInit);
            }
            return PartialView("_InitResult", inits);
        }
```

#### Partial Result View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WagersDesigns.ViewModels.VMInitiatives>

<table>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var roll in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @roll.Result
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### Segment of Razor page:

```
...
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <diV id="resultList">

                </diV>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                <button id="clear" onclick="clearcontent('resultList')">Clear Rolls</button>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <div id="initiatives">
                    @* display list of all character initiatives *@
                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">@Html.ActionLink("Roll Init", "RollInits", new { @class = "rollInit" }) |</td>
            <td valign="top">
                <div id="initiativerolls">

                </div>
            </td>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                <button id="clear" onclick="clearcontent('initiativerolls')">Clear Initiatives</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
...
```

Comment: You tend to get much better results if you don't make people guess what exactly is going wrong.  Please describe the error you're seeing and what you're expecting to see instead.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I think OP doesn’t have any error rather he is confused why the one script works and one doesn’t.

Comment: This question could be simplified a lot if you just list the broken script and explain the problem with it. It isn't really necessary to include the working one for "comparison" (especially since they aren't really identical).

Comment: @iRohitBhatia you don't consider it an error when code doesn't behave according to requirements?  It may not be producing a message, but it's still an error

Comment: I'm not sure, but maybe if you used a `<span class="rollInit">Roll Init</span>` instead of `@Html.ActionLink(...)` it'll work as you expect, and it's easy to make a `span` look like an `anchor` using some `css`

Comment: @Tibrogargan: it's in the first paragraph.  I did, however, edit it for clarity.  I want the second script to load data into the second div instead of to a new page.